# WPF Button Touch Focus

Tags: wpf, button, focus

I have a `Button` element in my xaml file (18 of them actually) that will be used exclusively on touch screens. During user testing it was discovered that when clicked, the `Button` was not turning the desired green color because the focused style was overriding the `Background` property on the element.

I've set the `Focusable` property to false, the `FocusVisualStyle` to `{x:Null}`, and attempted to tinker with the `FocusManager` in the `TouchUp` handler. None of these have worked, and I'm left wondering:

How do you prevent a `Button`'s focused style from ever occurring, or what is a valid solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although using a `Style` was not the preferred solution, Microsoft documentation on Visual Styles makes it clear that this is the correct approach:

> If you want UI changes for any type of focus, whether via mouse, keyboard, or programmatically, then you should not use focus visual styles, and should instead use setters and triggers in styles or templates that are working from the value of general focus properties such as IsFocused or IsFocusWithin.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/styling-for-focus-in-controls-and-focusvisualstyle#the-purpose-of-focus-visual-style

After digging into the styling a bit, the actual `Trigger` that was changing the style of the `Button` was the `isMouseOver` event.

Here is the solution for **touch only** devices.

```
<Style x:Key="TouchButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Finally, you apply the style to the `Button`'s that require it:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource TouchButton}" />
```